# Is it safe to travel to Morocco due to the Ebola outbreak?

Tags: health, morocco, event-based-effects

My family and I are due to travel to Marrakech and Agadir this week (Thusday 7th August) and despite the fact that the Ebola outbreak is mainly affecting West Africa, such as Sierra Leone, would it still be safe to travel?

Comment: "Safe" is an incredibly subjective term, and impossible to define without some metric.

Comment: It's also not a [terribly contagious disease](http://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2014/08/04/what-are-your-chances-getting-ebola/dsF58FxG8P3AlSKexoeQOL/story.html)... to catch it you must come in contact with the bodily fluids of an infected person. If you don't go around kissing strangers or touching people's open wounds, generally you should be safe anywhere you go.

Comment: @Flimzy All this sounds like (part of) an answer and kind of contradicts your earlier comment.

Comment: @Relaxed: The relative risk of catching Ebola in Morocco now versus, say, this time last year, is probably something like 300,000,000% higher. The absolute risk of catching it *anywhere* is tiny, if you're smart.  Which version of "safe" is the OP asking about?

Comment: @Flimzy My point is that you seemed comfortable using the word nonetheless. More importantly, it seems possible to write a comprehensive answer that would leave that decision to the reader. Frankly, your remarks regarding the supposed subjectivity of the question or relative risk sound like deliberate efforts to find something to object to rather than constructive criticism.

Comment: @pnuts Even in that case the previous question should be edited to reflect the current information. It does not warrant the creation of a new question.

Answer (score 2):

It is not meaningfully less safe to go to Morocco, now, in relation to the Ebola outbreak in west Africa. There are vastly more better and tighter commercial and social ties between the west African countries and France and the UK than with Morocco.